# probability that of 5 draws, you get 3 aces, with replacement?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> Suppose you are playing with a deck of 52 cards, 13 of each suit, what
>   is the probability that of 5 draws, you get 3 aces, with replacement?

when solving this Question i thought we get the probability of three aces and 2 probability of the rest (Which is one):

(4/52)*(4/52)*(4/52)=0.00004

Comment: Doesn't that seem awfully low to you?  In any case, your computation just computes the probability of getting three aces when you draw three cards with replacement.

Comment: If you draw with replacement then you can think of it as $5$ independent experiments that all have probability $\frac4{52}=\frac1{13}$ to succeed... Can you guess wich distribution is involved here?

Answer (score 0):

By symmetry don't consider suit.

You need any permutation of $(A, A, A, x_1, x_2)$ where $x_1,x_2\neq A$

If the xs are equal, there are $\binom{12}{1}5!/3!/2!$ wanted cases
If the xs are not equal, there are $\binom{12}{2}5!/3!$ wanted cases

Total cases are $13^5$, so you get $(\binom{12}{1}5!/3!/2!+\binom{12}{2}5!/3!)/13^5 = 0.387833867053782\%$

Comment: This is correct but somewhat overcomplicated.  As you suggest, lets ignore the non-Ace suits.  Thus we only have two cases, Ace or non-Ace.  So we have a binomial process with success probability $\frac 1{13}$.  It follows that the probability of getting exactly three wins out of five tries is $\binom 53\times \left( \frac 1{13}\right)^3\times \left( \frac {12}{13}\right)^2$.